# Remote login on website using php, curl and api

Tags: php, yelp

I am trying from 1 week to login on yelp using php, curl and api, but i am not success. I got this output from my code: `{"message": {"field": "signature", "text": "One or more parameters are missing in request", "code": 8, "version": "1.1.1", "request_id": "2a372375b650682c"}}`

Comment: Is that your email address and password?

Comment: yes, this is my yelp email and password

Comment: what api are you trying to log in on? seems they have more than 1, `Yelp Fusion` and `GraphQL`

Comment: what is `NonceUtil.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

First of, replace your passwords !

then you should watch at this part :

```
foreach($p as $oneKey=>$oneValue) {
    $string .= urlencode($oneKey) . urlencode($oneValue);
}
```

you need to seperate the strings like this :

```
$string = ""
foreach($p as $oneKey=>$oneValue) {
    $string .= ($string!="" ? "&" : "") .urlencode($oneKey) . "=" urlencode($oneValue);
}
```

Comment: i used your strings `$string = "";
foreach($p as $oneKey=>$oneValue) {
    $string .= ($string!="" ? "&" : "") .urlencode($oneKey) . "=". urlencode($oneValue);
}` but Same output. are you tried my code?

Comment: i got it from postfields `$p` and using this code `$hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $string, 'HMAC-SHA1', true);
$sig = '_'.base64_encode($hash);` sorry for not good english.

Comment: i mean where did you got your api documentation from ?

Comment: They have a api, if its not implemented there you should not implement it.

Comment: because you wont know how they generate each parameter

Comment: their api have not login feature.

Comment: They authentificate through a security token which needs to be generated on there side. see https://www.yelp.com/fusion

Comment: network traffic debug results showing me success code but when i tried to using php curl code then not working. i think, signature is the main problem

Comment: I got this client id: `Jjxm_adrqP5uVpAe5cvBKQ` and api_key: `WD9VmtpsDCq9w5UQsIlcGrJ9GvpfeINYrRACtU1vcm-P8K4uIatsm_fOWIPN4XXC58yJRpB252AhRrCd7NJWFTJpQW1W0AyxlCRoihMWxWy44AUEXkeGmLs2NM6OW3Yx` from their fusion app. can i generate signature using this 2 code?

Comment: that entire foreach loop can be replaced with this single line: `$string=http_build_query($p);` - the foreach loop is basically doing http_build_query's job manually - and poorly.

Comment: He was trying to generate an signature.

Comment: sure. and you should replace all of this: ```$string = ""
foreach($p as $oneKey=>$oneValue) {
    $string .= ($string!="" ? "&" : "") .urlencode($oneKey) . "=" urlencode($oneValue);
}
```  with this: `$string=http_build_query($p);`